# Is it possible to know how many objects of a type are loaded in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, memory-profiling

I would like to know if while debugging, is possible to know how many objects of a type are loaded using a Visual Studio 2013. I am currently developing in C#.

Comment: What do you mean by how many objects are loaded? You might add some debug code to your object's constructor/finalizer that counts them in a static field. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392075/how-can-i-find-out-how-many-objects-are-created-of-a-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: what's up with all the downvotes?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the edition of Visual Studio you're using whether there's native support for this with a nice GUI. The [.NET Memory Allocation Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx) can help you view the number of objects in memory, it ships with Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate. You can also use a more hard-core technique using [Sons-of-Strike](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can give you [very detailed information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx), should you know what to look for. SoS works with any version of Visual Studio and even with the basic [WinDbg debugger](http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx). Here's an additional [tutorial from the Microsoft P&P group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817660.aspx) on the subject. To get SoS you need to [download and install the Windows Debugging Tools whcih you can find here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx).

There are a number of 3rd party profilers as well, like:

- [Red-Gate Ants Memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/download)
- [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
- [Intel VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe)
- [SciTech .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)

Other similar questions on StackOverflow:

- [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
- [.NET Memory Profiling Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools)