# BaseClass with instance counter

Tags: c#

I have a base class and several derived classes (for example `Base` and `ChildA : Base`). Each time I create an instance of `ChildA` class, I want it to be assigned a unique instance number (similar to autoincrement IDs in relational databases, but for my classes in memory as opposed to in a database).

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392075/how-can-i-find-out-how-many-objects-are-created-of-a-class), but there is one distinct difference: I would like the **base class** to handle this automatically. For each of my derived classes (ChildA, ChildB, ChildC, etc.), I would like the base class to maintain a separate count and increment this when a new instance of that derived class is created.

So, the information held in my `Base` class might end up looking like this:

```
ChildA,5
ChildB,6
ChildC,9
```

If I then instantiate a new ChildB (`var instance = new ChildB();`), I would expect ChildB to be assigned the id 7, since it follows on from 6.

Then, if I instantiate a new ChildA, I would expect ChildA to be assigned the id 6.

-

How can I handle this within the constructor of my `Base` class?

Comment: What have you tried already? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @SerhiiVoichyk this isn't a duplicate of that. the other question does not deal with derived classes

Comment: @SerhiiVoichyk - almost all of those answers use a single static variable, which isn't going to work here where we're trying to put the functionality in a base class

Comment: To me it seems every *derived* class has its own counter, not the *base*-class. Making it a good fit for the duplicate.

Comment: @HimBromBeere He wants to have the **whole logic in the base class**. It's not a diuplicate. I hate this "close bc duplicate" on SO when it's not.

Comment: @Adrian I agree that this point differes from the duplicate. However I would hold the question on hold, because it´s unclear what OP actually wants and what he has tried already, making it to be closed as unclear anyway. There´s no way to answer that question other than **guessing**.

Comment: @HimBromBeere On hold is fine. I just think an answer would be valuable though, if the question was better imo.

Comment: @Adrian You´re right in **if** the question was better phrased. Currently any pootential answer is just a guess.

Comment: @Mobz, better explain your question, show what you have tried, and i am sure this will be reopened

Comment: My problem is I'm working in the dark on this, I don't really know where to start. I'm not sure how to explain it any better..
As @HimBromBeere said it is important to me that the Whole logic is in the base class. I don't want to copy the same code into all my class's

Comment: Are you saying that you want each derived type to have its own auto-incrementing id set, where each time you instantiate the derived class, it increments that id by 1, but you want that logic to live in the base class?

Comment: @John Yes that is want im looking for!

Comment: Could you please add this information to your question together with some sample-classes that show your class-hierarchy and where the counter should be accessable/defined? Makes it much easiert to get an image of your story.

Comment: @Mobz I have edited your question (after your edit, I know) to (hopefully) more clearly illustrate what you're trying to achieve. Feel free to roll it back if it isn't what you want.

Comment: @John I´m not that convinced, if editing the question so heavily really maintains the original OPs intent.

Comment: Thank you very much @John! That is really kind of you. You hit the nail on the head with that edit.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, I know what you mean. It seems I was correct in my understanding though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a static `Dictionary<Type, int>` inside the base class where you keep track of derived instances by type. Since `this` will be of the derived type, you can use `this.GetType()` as the key inside the dictionary.

```
class Base
{
    static Dictionary<Type, int> counters = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    public Base()
    {
        if (!counters.ContainsKey(this.GetType()))
            counters.Add(this.GetType(), 1);
        else
            counters[this.GetType()]++;
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType() + " " + counters[this.GetType()]);
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    new Derived();
    new Derived2();
    new Derived();
}
```

Output:

```
Derived 1 
Derived2 1
Derived 2
```

---

For thread safety, you can use a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` instead of `Dictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary`? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You should use `counters.TryGetValue` instead of `counters.ContainsKey`. This will prevent looking for a key twice.

Comment: Are you asking or saying? this is your answer, I was just commenting on it. If you think a concurrentDictionary is a better solution, you should edit that into your answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Wel, it´s not explicitely mentioned in the question, so I wouldn´t specifically consider this.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian for at great solution! It is now a part of my code and works great! And thank you all for your comments!
Thanks John for making my question more Stackoverflow friendly - which is a skill I surely lag!

Answer (score 0):

Or a thread safe version

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public static ConcurrentDictionary<Type,int> Counter = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int>();   
   public BaseClass() => Counter.AddOrUpdate(GetType(), 1, (type, i) => i + 1);
}
```

**Usage**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   Console.WriteLine("Creating " + new A());

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   Console.WriteLine("Creating " + new B());

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
   Console.WriteLine("Creating " + new C());

foreach (var item in BaseClass.Counter.Keys)
   Console.WriteLine(item + " " + BaseClass.Counter[item] );
```

**Ouput**

```
Creating ConsoleApp8.A
Creating ConsoleApp8.A
Creating ConsoleApp8.B
Creating ConsoleApp8.B
Creating ConsoleApp8.B
Creating ConsoleApp8.B
Creating ConsoleApp8.C
ConsoleApp8.A 2
ConsoleApp8.C 1
ConsoleApp8.B 4
```

[Full Threaded Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zJjCpd)